# How to forward edit text box to intent url in ADT?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

So I'm fairly new to Java coding and I'm trying to create a simple code to have an edit text value act as a url for an intent internet command. I'm using this in Eclipse and ADT. The following is my java code.

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText UR_L=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ur_l);
            String sUR_L= new String(UR_L.getText().toString());

        Intent brwsrintnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sUR_L));
            startActivity(brwsrintnt);
            }
            });
```

In my layout I have a 2 buttons and an edit box but the edit box reflects a missing input type error.  I have no idea how to fix this and I've looked many places.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be that the EditText is never intialized until you have already hit the button, so when you go to get text from it, it doesn't know the user has already entered something. Try moving

```
EditText UR_L=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ur_l);
```

to just before you set the OnClickListener and see if anything changes

Comment: When I do that it says my command to convert the edittext to string has an undefined variable of UR_L.  I assume this is because I start a new public void.  The same thing occurs if I place both that line and the line

    String sUR_L= new String(UR_L.getText().toString());

before the OnClickListener.